# jquery - moving li element out of the parent ul, and retaining position

Tags: jquery, dom, element

I need to move li element out of its parent ul and into master parent ul.

I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( init );

function init() {

 // Move
  $('ul#listcomments').append( $('.children>li') );
  // Delete
  $('.children').remove();
}

</script>

</head>
<body>



<ul id="listcomments">
<li>Comment 1</li>
<li>Comment 2</li>
<li>Comment 3</li>
<li>Comment 4</li>
<li>Comment 5 <ul class="children"><li>Child comment of #5 is this</li></ul></li>
<li>Comment 6</li>
<li>Comment 7</li>
<li>Comment 8</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to achieve this:
* that is, make child li#5child to get out of ul and li and appear right below li.

```
<ul id="listcomments">
<li>Comment 1</li>
<li>Comment 2</li>
<li>Comment 3</li>
<li>Comment 4</li>
<li>Comment 5</li>
<li>Child comment of #5 is this</li>
<li>Comment 6</li>
<li>Comment 7</li>
<li>Comment 8</li>
</ul>
```

Instead I get:
* append drops li outside, but puts it at the very end of ul#listcomments

```
<ul id="listcomments">
<li>Comment 1</li>
<li>Comment 2</li>
<li>Comment 3</li>
<li>Comment 4</li>
<li>Comment 5 </li>
<li>Comment 6</li>
<li>Comment 7</li>
<li>Comment 8</li>
<li>Child comment of #5 is this</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this explains it better than using words. It's pretty simple as a concept, but with my limited skills, I couldn't come up with anything better.

help! :)

*notice: naming and numbering of lis is arbitrary. And child comment can appear within any # li. Content is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( init );

function init() {
    $('.children').each(function() {
        // save
        $a=$(this).children('li');
        // Move
        $($a.parent().parent()).after($a);
        // Delete
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
</script>
```

**This will solve your problem no matter how many `ul` child elements exist, and no matter how many `li` child elements they have.**

Comment: also this approach doesnt work. if I have more than 1 child comment, I will end up with duplicates :(

like this:

    Comment 1  
    Child comment of #1 is this  
    Child comment of #5 is this  
    Comment 2  
    Comment 3  
    Comment 4  
    Comment 5  
    Child comment of #1 is this  
    Child comment of #5 is this  
    Comment 6  
    Comment 7  
    Comment 8

Answer (score 1):

Try to use method `.after()`.
Replace `$('ul#listcomments').append( $('.children>li') );` to

```
$($('.children')[0].parentNode).after($('.childer > li'));
```

Comment: I found a problem with this approach. if I have more than two child elements to get out of li, hierarchy will be flowed. for example first child comment under #1 and #5, in this case unwrapped child comment #1 and #5 will both go under #1 parent comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method:

```
$(".children > li").unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this

```
var a = $('ul.children').html();
  //grab the li

$('ul.children').remove();
  //remove the ul

$('ul#listcomments li:eq(4)').after(a);
  //add the li after the 5th li in the  parent list
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/aDWJF/1/

Comment: Hi, naming and numbering of lis is arbitrary. And child comment can appear within any # li. So your code will work only in this particular case, but with anything dynamic it wont fit.

Comment: That's good to know information @SandroDzneladze.  You should edit the question to include it.